# Adding folders to publish path

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, visual-studio-2012, publishing

My project is done in vs 2012 professional(.NET 4.5).

I have to add three folders for reports which are generated to be kept. How can I make sure these extra folders are also published during project publishing. Now I have to manually create the said folders in published IIS folder.

I am sure there is some setting for making my need fullfilled. Any help will be appreciated

Comment: Simply create three new folders in the project root folder with the same name.

Comment: Have you tried it. Adding folders does not make it part of publishing particularity these custom added folders

Comment: Actually what is the purpose of this folder? just you want to store the generated report or something else?

Comment: It could be a font folder. As You said it's also for saving generated report aslo

Comment: Then you don't need any configuration things. After the successful publish, just create those folders with the same folder structure as you defined in the code and also give the full access to those folders. one more thing, make sure the folder paths are well handled in code.